# AI performing a random action every n seconds in Java Game

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

Im implementing a game where an enemy AI performs a random action from a pre set amount of actions. Iv implemented the performing of a random action, but this means every single update of the game a new action is performed. Rather i would like the AI to perform an action every 1 second for example. How would this be done ? Here is my random action code:

```
public class RandomAction implements Controller {
    Action action = new Action();

    @Override
    public Action action() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        action.shoot = rand.nextBoolean();
        action.thrust = rand.nextInt(2);
        action.turn = rand.nextInt(3) - 1;
        return action;
    }

}
```

Comment: As given, the question doesn't contain enough context. It depends on the overall structure of your program to determine if e.g. using a thread can solve that problem.

Comment: if its any help using something like thread.sleep would not work as there are other elements of the game that need to carry on being updated i.e the player ship that is controlled via the keyboard

Comment: If you have a separate thread for the enemy AI, it can perfectly well use `thread.sleep`. You need to take care of concurrency issues, though.

Comment: Ahh ok i see. Im rather beginner to java so excuse my lack of knowledge. How would i go about implementing something like that ?

Comment: There are many tutorials concerning threads, take a look at this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html The `MessageLoop` in this example is what would be the AI in your program, and `threadMessage` would be replaced by the part the starts the `Action` in your game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume thay your app calls `action()` method on different objects repeatedly and you want to change RandomAction behavior only once a second, not on every call. You can do this:

```
public class RandomAction implements Controller {
    Action action = new Action();
    Random rand = new Random();
    long updatedAt;

    public RandomAction() {
        updateAction(); // do first init
    }

    @Override
    public Action action() {            
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - updatedAt > 1000) {
            updateAction();
        }            
        return action;
    }

    private void updateAction() {
        action.shoot = rand.nextBoolean();
        action.thrust = rand.nextInt(2);
        action.turn = rand.nextInt(3) - 1;
        updatedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

As you can see, action is updated with random values only if 1 second passed since last update. Update time variable is set to current time after that.